# Convert spatial table into non-spatial table in Oracle

Tags: oracle-spatial

I want to convert a spatial table, registered with Geodatabase (SDE), into a non-spatial table using SQL Developer, what would it be the most efficient/elegant way of doing it?

Obviously, first I would make a copy of it before changing anything.

Having said that, I would also like to maintain the foreign keys, indexes and constraints of the non-spatial columns.

which would it be the best option from below?

1. DELETE the 'SHAPE' and the 'SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA' columns.
2. DROP the Spatial Metadata/Spatial indexes.
3. Export the table into a text/csv/excel/etc file and upload it as a new table without spatial attributes and then, re-create the foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Why not just `CREATE table non_spatial AS SELECT attr_1, attr_2, attr_3 FROM spatial_table;` followed by `DROP TABLE spatial_table;`

Comment: will the CREATE statement in that way keep the relationships, constraints, etc. of the newly created table?

Comment: No; I suggest to include those constraints in your question.

Comment: I don't understand why you use the third step. when you do steps 1,2 then you have done the job. The indices and constraints such as foreign keys are preserved.

Comment: The only safe way to unregister a table previously registered with a geodatabase is to drop the table *using ArcGIS*. Dropping columns fragments table contents, and it therefore not recommended.  There is no elegant solution here.